# Google font doesn't show up on iphone

Tags: iphone, fonts

I need to know why google font API just doesn't work on iPhone, it doesn't show the great font I have chosen for the site

http://studioteknik.ca/stada/

check out the font on sidebar... it should be COMPRESSED now it's normal

Comment: found : http://iosfonts.com/
and http://www.iphone-ipad-fonts.com/download.php

Comment: OK i load this : http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Economica and it display just a old ugly times... life sucks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a combination of http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ and @fontface, and it work beautifully !